# Argument exception with Text Box

Tags: c#, textbox

I have a text box. When I drag a file into it and click a button the file from text box is moved to another folder. But if I forget to drag a file to the text box and click a button, the program throws an Argument Exception that sourceFileName isnt't present.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // here occurs Argument Exception Because there isn't any TextBox.Text
    File.Copy(TextBox.Text, "C:/");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please drag a file to the Tex Box!");
        }
}
```

How can I catch that Argument Exception of a missing Source File?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for `string.IsNullOrEmpty` before `File.Copy` and if the `TextBox` is empty then `return` from the event.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please drag a file to the Tex Box!");
            return; // return from the event
        }

    File.Copy(TextBox.Text, "C:/");
}
```

Also its better if you use [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx), since it will check for `null`, `string.Empty` and white spaces (Only if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher)

Comment: Thank You! with return; the program doesn't throw any exception anymore!!

Comment: @orglce, you are welcome, you can `return` or use `if-else` like in other option. You may see [this question regarding early return from a function](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/should-i-return-from-a-function-early-or-use-an-if-statement)

Answer (score 2):

> But if I forget to drag a file to the text box

Then you need to do some error checking in your code.  If it's possible in the UI to click the button without specifying a file, then your code can't assume that the file name will be present.  (Currently it does.)

Try checking the condition before performing the file operations:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
    File.Copy(TextBox.Text, "C:/");
```

Maybe even take it a step further to check if the value actually is a valid file:

```
if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
    if (File.Exists(TextBox.Text))
        File.Copy(TextBox.Text, "C:/");
```

Add some `else` conditions to show appropriate messages to the user.  Conversely, you can disable the button in the UI until the text box has a value.  Or, well, you could take both approaches.

(As an aside, `TextBox` isn't a particularly good name for a variable.  That's the name of an actual class, and *probably* the same class as the variable itself.  It's best to differentiate between the class name and the variable instance name, especially if you're ever going to use static methods on that class.)

Answer (score 1):

Move your `String.IsNullOrEmpty` statement before the other statement.

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
       MessageBox.Show("Please drag a file to the Tex Box!");
    else
       File.Copy(TextBox.Text, "C:/");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why do you do the check after?

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox.Text))
    MessageBox.Show("Please drag a file to the Tex Box!");
else
    File.Copy(TextBox.Text, "C:/");
```

you only want to perform the action if it's valid.  Really you probably need a try/catch around the whole thing as multiple errors could happen

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use File.Exists to see if the file is there beforehand
I like to use exceptions for exceptional cases, but that's personal preference

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (File.Exists(TextBox.Text.Trim()))
  {
    File.Copy(TextBox.Text, "C:/");
  }
else
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Please drag a file to the Tex Box!");
    return;
  }
```